# Search highlighter in Java

Tags: java, colors, highlighting, bold

boldHighlight method takes text string and highlights in it q keywords via `<b></b>` tags

colorHighlight method takes text string and highlights int q keywords via `<b style='background-color: #color'></b>` with 12 alternating colors

```
String text = "The use of hello as a telephone greeting has been credited to Thomas
               Edison; according to one source, he expressed his surprise with a
               misheard Hullo. Alexander Graham Bell initially used Ahoy (as used on 
               ships) as a telephone greeting"

String keywords = "HELLO Surprise"
```

`boldHighlight(text, keywords); // will produce:`

> The use of `<b>hello</b>` as a telephone greeting has been credited to Thomas Edison; according     to one source, he expressed his `<b>surprise</b>` with a misheard Hullo. Alexander Graham Bell initially used Ahoy (as used on ships) as a telephone greeting`

`colorHighlight(text, keywords); // will produce:`

> The use of `<b style='background-color:#ffff66'>hello</b>` as a telephone greeting has been credited to Thomas Edison;>according     to one source, he expressed his `<b style='background-color:#a0ffff'>surprise</b>` with a misheard Hullo. Alexander Graham Bell initially used Ahoy (as used on ships) as a telephone greeting

---

## The question:

#### is there something I could use like third party library that would do similar job as bellow methods? Or if you look at the code, is there something that can be improved, to make the performance better and/or make it more elegant?`

---

```
private static final String[] colors = new String[]{"ffff66", "a0ffff", "99ff99", "ff9999", "ff66ff", "880000", "00aa00", "886800", "004699", "990099", "ffff66", "a0ffff"};

public static String safeCharWithSpace(String input) {
    input = input.trim();
    return Normalizer.normalize(input.toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}]+", " ");
}

private static String prepQuery(String q) {
    try {
        log.debug("qr encoded: " + q);
        q = URLDecoder.decode(q, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignore) {
    }
    log.debug("qr decoded: " + q);

    return removeIgnoreCase(q, stopWords);
}

public static String boldHighlight(String text, String q) {
    return highlight(text, q, false);
}

public static String colorHighlight(String text, String q) {
    return highlight(text, q, true);
}

private static String replaceWord(String text, String keyword, int colorNumber, boolean useColor) {
    String color = "";
    keyword = safeCharWithSpace(keyword);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(keyword) && !StringUtils.isWhitespace(keyword)) {
        if (useColor) color = " style='background-color: " + colors[colorNumber] + "'";
        return text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + keyword + ")(?!([^<]+)?>>)", "<b" + color + ">$1</b>");
    } else
        return text;
}

public static String highlight(String text, String q, boolean useColor) {
    String qr = prepQuery(q);
    String rtn = null;
    int i = 0;

    if (qr.startsWith("\"")) {
        String keywords = StringUtils.remove(qr, "\"");
        rtn = replaceWord(text, keywords, 0, useColor);
    } else {
        String[] keywords = qr.split("\\s");
        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            rtn = replaceWord(text, keyword, i, useColor);
            if (useColor) {
                if (i < 11) i++;
                else i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

for removal of stop words `removeIgnoreCase()`  in `prepQuery()` method refer to my other post: [Removing strings from another string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, well you could go about it a few different ways.

1. You could [call a static method](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_54).

   i.e.

   ```
   ${statics["java.lang.System"].currentTimeMillis()}
   ```
2. The MVC thing to do would be to do this processing before the template is processed, but I know your just maintaining the code.

It looks like it is just doing several replace all's, so a change to a Java method should work.  I have to suggesst you look at the [escaping tools](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_escape.html) Freemarker has.

Freemarker really has great [documentation](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html), and built ins cover many situations.

Comment: I have no idea what those macros are trying to do, but if you wanted to move that logic to Java, you could use a static method.