# java tokenizer or word breaker, and for different languages

Tags: java, normalization, wordbreaker

I wonder if there is some java based language utility out there that can help do the following  string tokenize or word break and noise removing

So for a string

```
Friday's meeting is wonderful
```

expected result will be a series of words

```
Friday meeting wonderful
```

where the 's and is got removed

And for string

```
I went to the farmer's market
```

expected result will be words

```
went farmer market
```

where I, to, the, and 's got removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general solution to this problem, because (not least) your notion of "noise" is ill-defined ... and most likely different to other peoples'.

If I was implementing this (and I agreed with your notion of "noise") I would:

1. Tokenize using whitespace and accepted punctuation as delimiters.
2. Strip quotes
3. Strip apostrophies
4. Normalize hyphenation (maybe just remove the hyphens)
5. Use a stop-word filter to get rid of the "noise" words.

In short, you are going to have to write a non-trivial amount of code to do this.

---

Of course, stripping the "noise" words is strip information that is relevant to a proper semantic analysis of the text.  ("I hit the ball" and "You hit a ball" are saying different things.)

Answer (score 1):

I've played with the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) before. It's an NLP engine which has good enough results for most purposes. It'll give you a lot of power in choosing specifically which kinds of words you want to keep.

[Online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at this? I also know there is a String Tokenizer class but that could be challenging to use for your purpose.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a utility that would do it for you out of the box but may be look at this - [Removing strings from another string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769282/removing-strings-from-another-string-in-java). Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Probably it´s not the best solution, but you can use replaceAll method from String class, replacing the noise for an empty String.

For example, something like: line.replaceAll("'s", "");

Comment: This is a very hard problem and such a simplistic answer breaks very quickly.  What happens to `He was known for being 'strange'` ?