# removing words from a string in java

Tags: java, android

Could anyone tell me what is wrong in my code?

I am trying to pass a string to function `removeWords()` and this function removes some information from the `String`.

For example if I pass:

> "I Have a Headach"

the function should return:

> "Headach"

However, my function is not working:

```
public class WordChosen extends Activity {

    private TextView wordsList;
    private String symptom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_chosen);

        //Getting String from VoiceRecognition Activity and displaying it

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String wordChosen = intent.getExtras().getString("wordChosen");

        //casting the string with TextView to display the result
        wordsList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordChosen);

        Log.v("Word List:", "+++++"+wordChosen);
        //Setting text to be displayed in the textView

        removeWords(wordChosen);
        Log.v("removewords:", "------- message is displayed");



    }

    public void removeWords(String wordList)
    {
        ArrayList<String> stopList = null;
        stopList.add("i");
        stopList.add("have");
        stopList.add("a");

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordList.split(" ")));
        for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<stopList.size();j++)
            {

                if (result.get(i).equals(stopList.get(j))) { 
                    break;
                } 
                else { 

                   if(j==stopList.size()-1)
                    {

                       wordsList.setText(result.get(i));

                     }
                   }
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: What is it returning for your input?

Comment: What's you current results?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You will need to return a new String from your method.

Comment: If you want to delete specific words from your string, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4769336/1276636) should help you.

Answer (score 12):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "I Have a Headach";
    String remove = "I Have a ";
    System.out.println(removeWords(word, remove));
}

public static String removeWords(String word ,String remove) {
    return word.replace(remove,"");
}
```

output : `Headach`

Comment: While I guess this technically offers an alternative solution to the question asked, it has limited scope and probably isn't too helpful to OP.

Comment: @AndyPerfect correct. A much better answer (to remove multiple words from string) can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4769336/1276636).