# How to remove stopwords from a sentence?

Tags: java

I have a list of stopwords where I want to remove **all stopwords** that exist in a sentence from the stopword-list. I'm currently using regex. I have to convert it to lower case as per the requirements that i need to meet.

However, the problem is that stopwords still exists in the sentence.

```
// List of stopwords
List<String> stopwords = new ArrayList<>();
stopwords.add("is");
stopwords.add("a");
// the stopword list goes on ....

// Sentence
String sentence = "autism    autism is a neurodevelopmental";

// Remove stop words in the sentence
String stopwordsRegex = stopwords.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|", "\\b(", ")\\b\\s?"));
String removedSW = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll(stopwordsRegex, "");

System.out.println(removedSW);
```

Comment: a replaceAll with space is all you need. but I see no need for that stopwordsRegex variable. probably that's where your error is. Also: this, stopwords.add('is'); won't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing strings from another string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769282/removing-strings-from-another-string-in-java)

Comment: I have edited my post so that my list would take in "is" instead of 'is'. And you mean: `String removedSW = sentence.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ")`?

Comment: I tested your code in a java 11 jshell, and the result was "autism    autism neurodevelopmental". That's the wanted result, no ? Is your example reproducing your problem on your side ?

Comment: I'm actually using using scala spark Java API. I just tested the my code on an online compiler code and is working fine. I guess theres some issue with my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stopwordsRegex = stopwords.stream()
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(?i)\\b(", ")\\b\\s?"));
String removedSW = sentence.replaceAll(stopwordsRegex, "");
```

Everything is fine, just `(?i)` will add an *ignore-case*, so the sentence may keep its upper case. It might have been an upper-case stop word like `"I"`.
How to make words in a stream lower-case added (but not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

this works as well:

```
 for (String stopword : stopwords){
      sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\b" + stopword + "\\b", "");
 }
```